# is it a good practice to include all prototypes in one header file?

Tags: c, clang

I've seen similar questions but I didn't understand yet.

is it a good practice to include all prototypes in one header file then including it in each file that need a prototype or create a header file for each .c file's prototypes.

The language I'm using is C.

Comment: Do not ask multiple unrelated questions in one post.

Comment: Does the standard C library put all of its prototypes in one file? Does macOS? Does POSIX? Does Windows? No, they do not, and neither should you.

Comment: I have the functions in many headers, then I declare a macro that includes all of them. Here's an exmaple: ```#define INCLUDE_HEADERS #include <stdio.h> \ #include <stdlib.h>```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem of one single header containing all the function declarations included by all modules is that when you touch it (and that will probably be often as all prototypes are there) every single module will need to be recompiled.

If you're using "C" then this is probably not a big issue with current computers unless your program is huge.

With "C++" things are different as the compilers are much slower at processing source code because of templates, and recompiling everything at each change of a single prototype could be very annoying.

Comment: I think it is the least important problem.

Comment: @gulpr may be you probably never worked on big C++ projects that take several minutes to compile on 32 core machines... I can assure you it's quite annoying (we don't have a single header, but there is one header that ends up included everywhere and touching it is not fun). By the way we're not template fanatics, it's not hard to imagine real world big projects requiring hours if templates are abused.